# How do I figure out what this encoded value is?

Tags: unicode, encoding, character-encoding

I am capturing some traffic with wireshark and need to decipher some encoded values. The values are read by our proprietary program and converted. I need to know how that conversion is done.

Here are some values I know:

| Encoded | Actual |
| --- | --- |
| 0x0000000000000000 | 0 |
| 0x404bc00000000000 | 55.5 |
| 0x4066800000000000 | 180 |
| 0x40ac200000000000 | 3600 |
| 0xc014000000000000 | -5 |

EDIT:

I added a few more I have found. It looks like the first digit (maybe the first 2) is a sign. Closest thing I have come across is that it could be is a signed floating point. But that does not work.

Comment: Why do you believe this is related to unicode or character encoding? These are definitely not the unicode encodings for those character sequences.

Comment: I have no idea what it is. I am stabbing in the dark.

Comment: I just need to know how/why those hex values are equivalent to those decimal values.

Comment: So your question is really about Wireshark? Regardless, your tags are very misleading, and the entire question is way off topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The values you have shown are just standard [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) [double-precision floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) numbers, stored as a 64bit data type, like `double` commonly used in C/C++, C#, Java, etc.

If you really want to understand how these values work, try plugging the hex values into [Floating Point to Hex Converter](https://gregstoll.com/%7Egregstoll/floattohex/) using the "Convert to double" option, it will show you the math involved. For example:

[image]